# Formatting Apex input field labels in a repeat

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

I have a field set in SF that I am using in a Visual Force page and the formatting of the field labels is not cooperating exactly.

Here is my code.

```
<apex:pageblocksection columns="1" title="[...]" collapsible="false">
    <apex:repeat value="{!fields2}" var="c">
        <apex:inputfield value="{!ghostacc[c.fieldPath]}" required="true" style="white-space: nowrap; position: relative;"/> 
    </apex:repeat>      
</apex:pageblocksection>
```

The result is a label for the input field that allows for word wrap. Is there something that I am missing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`style` attribute on `<apex:inputField>` applies to the input itself, not the label next to it.

Try explicitly specifying the label and the input, something like this?

```java
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    <apex:outputLabel value="{!c.label}" style="nowrap magic goes here">
    <apex:inputfield value="{!ghostacc[c.fieldPath]}" required="true" />
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

Comment: Sorry it has taken me a while to get back to this answer. I will try this and see what it does.